# Reshape API response object from strings to numerical values in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json, stringify

I am working with the Alpha Vantage API on [RAPID API](https://rapidapi.com/alphavantage/api/alpha-vantage?endpoint=apiendpoint_55220bb2-8a64-4cde-89e1-87ec00947f57) and the schema of the response object I am getting from the API is as follows:

[image: Rapid API JSON response object]

I am passing this object to a chart, so I need the " " marks around the numerical values in the key-value pairs removed so the chart can use the data. Is there an easy way to do this? I have googled for a JavaScript function that does the opposite of the [Stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) function, but so far no luck. Any ideas would be a big help!

The API response JSON object schema is as follows:
[image: API response object schema]

If it helps, here is the API I am querying: https://rapidapi.com/alphavantage/api/alpha-vantage?endpoint=apiendpoint_55220bb2-8a64-4cde-89e1-87ec00947f57

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use `Number()` function or multiply by 1

e.g.

`"999.887" * 1 = 999.887`

Answer (score 1):

The Number() function converts the object argument to a number that represents the object's value.

```
 var x4 = "999.887";
 Number(x4) // returns 999.887
```